# How to connect OpenShift with a private BitBucket Repository

Tags: git, svn, github, bitbucket, openshift

I want to host a website on OpenShift but I want my code to synchronize automatically with a "free but private" service like Git, so I found BitBucket.

I tried to connect it by my self by pasting this key from my OpenShift app:

> ssh://530910bd5973ca01ea00007d@XXXXXXXXXX.rhcloud.com/~/git/XXXXXXXXXX.git/

into:

> BitBucket -> Repository -> Import Repository -> Old Repository.

But I get this error:

> Unsupported protocol. Please use 'http://', 'https://' , 'svn://' or
>   'git://.

I believe I have the same issue as this guy:
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/connect-to-bitbucket-repository-from-openshift-app

But I don't understand how to apply this solution. Before you ask, yes I'm new to Github, BitBucket and OpenShift etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of searching on Google I found the solution...

I suggest to people with (almost) the same issue as I had, or who are also beginners like me with OpenShift and BitBucket to read and understand this well written tutorial by Redhat:
https://www.openshift.com/developers/install-and-setup-putty-ssh-client-for-windows

After that small tutorial, I was able to connect OpenShift with BitBucket through SourceTree.

Comment: I think I understand how SSH etc work but I still don't understand how to actually connect BitBucket with OpenShift. It seems the best you could do is push to both Bitbucket *and* Openshift, [as per instructions here](https://forums.openshift.com/connect-to-bitbucket-repository-from-openshift-app), but you can't actually connect Openshift *to* Bitbucket, is that correct? Or am I missing something that enabled you to actually "connect OpenShift with BitBucket through SourceTree"?? I.e. you only push to BitBucket and OpenShift "pulls" those changes automatically. And what does SourceTree do?

Comment: I just wanted to add that I was running into this same issue, and I literally tried everything, but Sourcetree and Git Bash just couldn't connect to the OpenShift remote. Weird part was I could ssh fine into my OpenShift remote using PuTTy and the exact same PuTTy ssh key SourceTree was using! But after about an hour, SourceTree finally started recognizing the `ssh://...rhcloud.com/~/git...` remote, so if all else fails, try waiting a bit

Comment: @laggingreflex yes, that's not possible, when I made this question/answer I though I could use Bitbucket within Openshift, but that was wrong, because I didn't fully understand Git at that moment. You do can connect SourceTree with Openshift, and that's what the tutorial is for and what I actually meant.

Comment: I used to update Openshift via command line git just fine. Then I setup my project to use bitbucket, to git to there via command line. Works. But I no longer git to openshift! So my updated code is not getting to my cloud app on Openshift!  I was hoping you had determined how to git to bitbucket by command line and had a setup so the flow also continued to update openshift.  Did you get to there or stop at using SourceTree?

Comment: link is dead :(