# Importing openshift project into eclipse fails because of private key

Tags: eclipse, git, openshift

I am trying to import an openshift application into eclipse.

I get the following error message:

```
Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
 Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.
ssh://57766e5e0c1e66b5c5000073@javaapp-tcinfopage.rhcloud.com/~/git/javaapp.git/: ProxyHTTP: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I generated new RSA keys several times in Eclipse.

In the ssh preferences, the private and the public key are referenced.

I also included the public key into my openshift account

I have no idea what to do and I can't find a solution anywhere.

What is going on here?

**EDIT**

```
D:\TEST>git clone ssh://5777ab8d0c1e662a4d0001af@javacloudapp-tcinfopage.rhcloud.com/~/git/javacloudapp.git/
Cloning into 'javacloudapp'...
Warning: Permanently added 'javacloudapp-tcinfopage.rhcloud.com,52.20.106.184' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\TEST>
```

Comment: Where is remote repository hosted?

Comment: I see a connection time out error in line 3 of the error. Anyone sure if this is what we get even if there is a Authentication Failure? Cuz I guess it would say Auth fail at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349162/not-able-to-import-openshift-application-in-eclipse and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804071/private-key-authentication-failed-error-in-eclipse-for-openshift have some suggestions. kindly check if your ip and port are reachable with telnet.

Comment: @Manish Isn't that 57766e5e0c1e66b5c5000073@javaapp-tcinfopage.rhcloud.com/~/git/javaapp.git/ ?

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan I looked at those... The steps described there didn't help.

Comment: @user3629892, it is a Git remote repository (something very much similar to GitHub or BitBucket). You need to add your public key to the repository account.

Comment: @Manish Well, that would be Openshift. I did that... several times... doesn't work, no matter what I try or do...

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look on OpenShift Online console. You need to add your public key (.pub file) in step 3 while you are creating your application in OpenShift. See attached screen shot.[image: Adding SSH Key in OpenShift application Git SCM]

Comment: I am not sure, why the screenshot link is not working.

Comment: I have done that as well... several times. I created and recreated the app various times. I created ssh keys in eclipse and then later tried it directly in the git bash... Nothing has worked so far... I just recreated the app and pasted the key. I then cloned the whole thing from git via the command line, see my edit.

Comment: It is strange that your SSH public key is not working. Ensure that there are no line breaks or spaces in the public key(in case you haven't).

Comment: You can try connecting OpenShift with private BitBucket Repository. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972377/how-to-connect-openshift-with-a-private-bitbucket-repository?rq=1